# What disadvantages come with using TLP?

Tags: power-management, tlp

I use Ubuntu on desktops and laptops and am making a custom script to set things up for my school. I just discovered [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) to improve power comsumption for the laptops and want to include it in my script. Most of what I hear is great. [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/tlp-05-released-install-it-in-ubuntu.html) and [makeuseof](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-increase-battery-life-tlp-linux/) seem to recommend it. Yet, it is not included with any version or derivative of Ubuntu that I know of. [Arch Linux includes it in it's official repositories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP), but Ubuntu requires adding a third party PPA. So, this leads me to believe that is has enough issues or is too new to include by default or even in the default repositories.

- Am I asking for trouble by installing it on desktop hardware, or will it just stay in the AC mode and have no effect?
- Will I likely see any kernel freezing or instability with Ubuntu 12.04 and TLP?
- Has anyone had any cause to remove TLP?

Comment: I've been using TLP in my laptop for quite a while, and had no problems that I can trace back to it.